# Prove that there exists no prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $\phi(n)\mid(n-1)$, then prove that there exists no prime $p$ such that $p^2\mid n$.

This means that $n$ must be a product of different primes. But how do I prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\ge 2$ and $\phi(n)\mid n-1$, then let $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}$ be the unique prime factorization of $n$. Then $$\phi(n)=p_1^{\alpha_1-1}p_2^{\alpha_2-1}\cdots p_n^{\alpha_n-1}\left(p_1-1\right)\left(p_2-1\right)\cdots\left(p_n-1\right)$$

Therefore, if there exists a prime $p$ such that $p^2\mid n$, then $p\mid \phi(n)$. Since we're given $\phi(n)\mid n-1$, we get $p\mid n-1$. But $p\mid n$, so $p\mid n-(n-1)=1$, contradiction.

By the way, if $n\ge 2$ and if there is no prime $p$ such that $p^2\mid n$, then $n$ is called [square-free](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html). $1$ is by convention also square-free.

Answer (score 1):

If $p^2\mid n$, then $n=p^km$ with $k\ge 2$ and $p\nmid m$. By multiplicativity of $\phi$, we have $\phi(n)=\phi(p^k)\phi(m)=p^{k-1}(p-1)\phi(m)$. This is a multiple of $p$, but $n-1$ is not, i.e., $\phi(n)\nmid (n-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $p^2 \mid n$ then $p\mid \phi(n)\Rightarrow p\mid n-1$
So, we have:

$p\mid n$ and $p\mid n-1\Rightarrow p\mid 1$.
Contradiction.